# React, UseContext changes not reflecting immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-context

When I log out from the `Home` page, the state gets updated and the page shows a login option, but after logging in again, the page again shows a login option untill refreshed, after refreshing the page, it displays the username? Why does the context value does not reflect immediately?

Login.js:

```
const submit = () => {
  Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/login", data).then((res) => {
    localStorage.setItem("bankDetails", res.data[0].acc_no);
    navigate("/Home");
  });
};

return (
  <form onSubmit={submit}>
    <input ... />
    ...
  </form>
)
```

Home.js:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { LoginContext, DetailsContext } from "../App";

function Account() {
  const isValid = useContext(LoginContext);
  const userDetails = useContext(DetailsContext);

  const load = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("bankDetails");
    window.location.reload();
  }

  return isValid ? (
   <div className="personal-info">
     <h3>Welcome {userDetails.Username}</h3>
     <h3 onClick={load}>LogOut</h3>
   </div>
  ) : (
    <h1>You Need to Login First !!!</h1>
  );
}
```

App.js:

```
export const LoginContext = React.createContext();
export const DetailsContext = React.createContext();

function App() {
  const username = localStorage.getItem("bankDetails");
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState();
  const [isValid, setisValid] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (username !== null) {
      Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/userDetails", {
        username: username,
      }).then((res) => {
        if (res.data.err) {
          console.log("err");
        } else {
          setUserDetails(res.data.details[0]);
          setisValid(true);
        }
      });
    }
  }, [username]);

  return (
    <LoginContext.Provider value={isValid}>
      <DetailsContext.Provider value={userDetails}>
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/Login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/Home" element={<Home />} />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </DetailsContext.Provider>
    </LoginContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because inside `submit` function you didn't ask the context to update anything. Your `App` component is not watching changes inside the `localStorage`, the only thing you are updating after login. `App` as you did checks the `localStorage` only on load. That's why it works when you log in and then refresh the page.

What you can do that wouldn't change that much your current structure is to change `App` component as follow (I added comments where I changed things):

```
export const LoginContext = React.createContext();
export const DetailsContext = React.createContext();

function App() {
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState();
  const [isValid, setisValid] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // I moved this line here in the callback
    const username = localStorage.getItem("bankDetails");
    if (username !== null) {
      Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/userDetails", {
        username: username,
      }).then((res) => {
        if (res.data.err) {
          console.log("err");
        } else {
          setUserDetails(res.data.details[0]);
        }
      });
    }
  }, [isValid]); // I changed the dependencies array

  return (
    // I'am passing down setisValid as part of LoginContext
    <LoginContext.Provider value={{ isValid, setisValid }}>
      <DetailsContext.Provider value={userDetails}>
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/Login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/Home" element={<Home />} />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </DetailsContext.Provider>
    </LoginContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Then grab both of `isValid` and `setisValid` inside `Login` component. Change your `submit` function and add an `useEffect` that would do the redirection. Like so:

```
const {isValid, setisValid} = useContext(LoginContext);

const submit = () => {
  Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/login", data).then((res) => {
    localStorage.setItem("bankDetails", res.data[0].acc_no);
    setisValid(true);
};

useEffect(()=>{
  if(isValid){
   navigate("/home")
  }

},[isValid])
```